# Anchor that doesn't scroll to the top

Tags: javascript, html, css, anchor, anchor-scroll

I have a table with a floating thead. And in my table, I have multiple cells `td` with anchors to other cells in this table.

My problem is when a user click on an anchor, the anchor took him to the anchor, but he cannot see the element because the element is under the floating thead.

How can I have an anchor that took the user to the `anchor + 100px` to the top, to allow him to see the targeted element ?

Comment: change where the anchor points at, to account for the header, or add some code to detect those clicks and adjust the scroll point by 100px.

Comment: Try `<a href="javascript:void(0);">Click here</a>`

Comment: Please share your code:

Comment: @Pugazh I don't think that's the solution, the problem is other than jumping to the top of the page .

Comment: Program the anchor jump using Javascript rather than using the default behavior and then add an offset the height of the floating thead.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a negative margin on the anchor, something like,

```
a[name] {
    position: relative;
    top: -150px;
    display: block;
}
```